# Please help me find a home for this question about GAP.

Tags: support

I'm looking to install GAP on my Android phone. I thought MSE would be a good place to ask for help with this since I suspect that others there would want to install it too.

Here is my question on the main site:

[Getting GAP on an Android Phone.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2977063/104041)

Please assist me on finding an appropriate home for the question as, as I have found, it is unwelcome on MSE.

Comment: Maybe android.SE?

Comment: Okay, that seems appropriate. Thank you, @AlexanderGruber. Please would you migrate it there for me? Otherwise, I think I have to wait for a while because there's a limit to how many questions one can ask in 90 minutes.

Comment: [Nevermind.](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/203261/234367)